# How to show data passed from Controller to View using jQuery in Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, view, controller

I am trying to show data which is passed from controller to blade and manipulate something with it in my view page. But I can see the my data passed correctly in my console but i am not getting it in my view file. **I am using Laravel 4**

Controller:

```
public function addRow()
{
    if(Request::ajax()){
        $row = Input::all();        
    }
    return View::make('add-stock')
        ->with('rows', $row);
}
```

View :

```
@if( !empty($rows) )
    @foreach($rows as $row)
        {{ $row[0]  }}
    @endforeach
@endif
```

route:

```
Route::post('add-stock/row','StockController@addRow');
```

jQuery :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('.rowForm').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            var rowVal = $('input[name=row]').val();

            //ajax post
            $.post('add-stock/row', {row:rowVal}, function(data){
                console.log(data);
            })
        })          


    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do like this.
Your ajax function........

```
public function addRow(){  

    $row = Input::all();

    return Response::json($row);
 }
```

And then your JQuery............

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.rowForm').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var rowVal = $('input[name=row]').val();

        //ajax post
        $.get('/add-stock/row?rowVal =' +rowVal , function(data){
            console.log(data);
             $('#rowVal ').empty();
        $.each(data,function(index,subcatObj)
        {
            $('#rowVal ').append('<option value="'+subcatObj.value+'">'+subcatObj.value+'</option>');
        })
        })
    })          


})
```

here #rowVal id of the div or select attribute

And atlast ...........the route file

```
Route::get('add-stock/row','StockController@addRow');
```

By the way you didn't specify from where JQuery will be called

Answer (score 0):

You can return the response with JSON content type. Luckily, Laravel provides a tool for that. You could do something right this

```
if(Request::ajax()){
        return Response::json(Input::all()); 
}
```

for more information: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#special-responses

Comment: how can i return the value to my desired view ??

Comment: Do you get anything at "console.log(data);"?

Comment: no it shows --  {"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","message":"Call to undefined function response()","file":"C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\easybiz\\app\\controllers\\StockController.php","line":93}}

Comment: Are you using Laraval 4 or 5?

Comment: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#special-responses  . Using the code in the link instead.